# Why my code doesn't work? "while" doesn't stop

Tags: python

Why it doesn't work? It should be stopped.
My `v == 3`.

`while t < 3`, it should be stopped,

You see in the code that my `t` is worth to `4`,

Why my `while` doesn't stop?

```
t = 4 < 3  == false
```

My code:

```
import random

stages = ['''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
 / \  |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
 /    |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
      |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|   |
      |
      |
=========''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
  |   |
      |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
      |
      |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
      |
      |
      |
      |
=========
''']

letters_number = 3

word_list = ["ardvark", "baboon", "camel"]

c = []
a = random.randint(0,(len(word_list) -1))
word_generator = word_list[a]
#print(word_generator)
d = 0
q = ""
z = 0
h = ''
t = 0
v = 3

for i in range(0,len(word_generator)):
    if i < len(word_generator):
      c += '_'

while  d  < len(word_generator) or int(t) < v:
  chose = input("Guess a letter\n")
  for i in range(0,len(word_generator)):

    if chose == word_generator[i]:
       c[i] = word_generator[i]
       d += 1
       #print("right")
    if c[i] == chose:
      z += 1000
    if c[i] != chose:
      z += -1
    if z < 0:
      h ="Wrong"
      z = 0
    else:
      h = "True"

  if h == "Wrong":
    t += 1

  print(c)
  print(z)
  print(h)
  h = ''
  z = 0
  print("t =",t)
if d == len(word_generator):
  print("you win")
if t == letters_number:
  print("you loose")
```

[image: screenshot of output from running code]

Comment: Please no not include images of text. They make it harder to reference your question and not all visitors will be able to view them due to proxies and other situations.

Comment: That text at the top looks suspiciously like non-code characters in an attempt to pad out the question length to meet the minimum requirements. It would be far more helpful if you could take a minute to explain what you are attempting to do and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

The while condition has two parts:

```
while  d  < len(word_generator) or int(t) < v
```

If the `t < v` part is false, the loop will still run if the `d < len()` part is true, because it is an `or` condition.

Comment: i resolve it    while  d  < len(word_generator) and int(t) < v: